# GroovyInterceptable and java callback

Tags: java, groovy, callback

How can I have the normal behavior for a GroovyInterceptable object (id est always call invokeMethod) where methods are called from Groovy and from Java.

I have a Groovy code where invokeMethod is customized.

```
interface ITest {
    void test()
}
class Toto implements ITest, GroovyInterceptable {
    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        System.out.println 'invokeMethod'
    }
    void test() {
        System.out.println 'test'
    }
}
Toto toto = new Toto()
toto.test() // display invokeMethod
```

If I have a callback that's still ok

```
class Tutu {
    def execute(ITest object) {
        object.test()
    }
}

Tutu tutu = new Tutu()
tutu.execute(toto)​ // display invokeMethod
```

But if the class Tutu is not in Groovy but in Java, the call to test() is direct, invokeMethod is never called.
That's seem clear that Java doesn't take care of GroovyInterceptable…

Obviously, Toto is a class in my project and Tutu is a class from one of my dependency that I can't modify.
So what to do on Toto to get the behavior in all cases.

The only solution that I see is some AST for each public/protected method

Comment: Java doesn't know about the Groovy Meta Protocols.  Therefore this won't work

Comment: AST or analog message dispatch: `object.invokeMethod("test", new Object[] {})`